# enumerating user scopes/slices

Tags: systemd, users, administration

I need to enumerate programaticaly all user scopes under a systemd instance.

currently i'm doing `systemctl --state running list-units user@*`

which gives me units such as `user@1000.service`

Then i use `systemctl --user --machine=1000@.host --type service --state running` where the machine= argument value is a loop/list from the result of the previous  list-units command, assuming the format will always be convertible from `user@1000.service => 1000@.host` with a simple regex/awk/etc.

Is this the best way? is this correct? any corner case i should know?